# Selecting all the input type checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to select all the checkboxes using the following code:

```
cell = row.insertCell(0);
if (tblname == "tblAttributes1") 
{
    el = document.createElement('input');
    el.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    el.setAttribute('name', 'nodeID');
    el.setAttribute('value', chkValue);
    el.setAttribute('onclick', function()
    {
        Toggle( "top_checkbox", this, "nodeID" )
    });
}
```

and html tag is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="top_checkbox" value="checkbox" title="Select/Deselect All" onClick="ToggleAll( this, 'nodeID' )">
```

Comment: You've asked about "selecting" checkboxes but shown code *creating* them...?

Answer (score 0):

If by "selected" you mean you want them to have the checkmark in them, you're looking for the `checked` property. And in general, you're using `setAttribute` where really you'd be better off using the reflected properties for things (especially the `onclick`, which just won't work cross-browser as you have it). So:

```
cell = row.insertCell(0);
if (tblname == "tblAttributes1") 
{
    el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = 'checkbox';
    el.name = 'nodeID';
    el.value = chkValue;
    el.checked = true; // Makes it checked
    el.onclick = function()
    {
        Toggle( "top_checkbox", this, "nodeID" )
    };
}
```

You probably also want to append `el` to something at some stage; presumably you're doing that in code you haven't shown.

---

Separately, I'd suggest using modern event handling techniques rather than `onclick`, such as `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` on IE8 and earlier).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a function as the onclick attribute, so the function.toString() will be set as the attribute value which won't be a valid value, instead you want to set the function reference as the value of the `el`'s `onclick` property

```
el.onclick = function () {
    Toggle("top_checkbox", this, "nodeID")
};
```